# java xml validation JDK 1.5 JDK 1.6 difference

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have a problem with Java xml validation.

I have the following xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="TEST">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="LAST_NAME">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:minLength value="1" />
              <xsd:maxLength value="30" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="FIRST_NAME">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:minLength value="1" />
              <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="DOB" nillable="true" type="xsd:date" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LAST_NAME>Lastname</LAST_NAME>
  <FIRST_NAME>Firstname</FIRST_NAME>
  <DOB xsi:nil="true"/>
</TEST>
```

The (simplified) code of my validator:

```
boolean valid=true;
try {
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(xsdInputStream);
    DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = parser.parse(xmlInputStream);
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    try {
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, e.getMessage(), e);
        valid = false;
    }

} catch( Exception ex ) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    valid=false;
}
```

The testprogram has a different behavior in JDK 1.5 and JDK 1.6. The xml is valid in JDK 1.5 but invalid in JDK 1.6. The error message is the following:

```
Element 'DOB' is a simple type, so it cannot have attributes, excepting those whose namespace name is identical to 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and whose [local name] is one of 'type', 'nil', 'schemaLocation' or 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation'. However, the attribute, 'xsi:nil' was found.
```

Which JDK is correct? How to change the xml/xsd to be valid in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting attributeFormDefault="qualified" in your XSD. That shouldn't make a difference, but it's a quick test.

Also: you don't set your DocumentBuilder to be namespace-aware. That would certainly break the validation, but it would break under 1.5 as well as 1.6.

And as a general comment, validation at the time of parsing is more useful, as you can see the line numbers of the content that failed validation. Here's the code to do it (`schema` is created previously):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setSchema(schema);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a bug in Java 6. You can always put xsi attributes in any element.

It's very similar to this bug,

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6790700

Try the fix 6u14. It most likely will fix yours too.

Comment: I was using 1.6.0_14. Now I've upgraded to 1.6.0_16 but the result is the same.